# python-all-dev similar packet for Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, dependencies

Following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681836/pyaudio-could-not-import-portaudio) I'm trying to install pyaudio library for Python. 
It works for python 2.7 but not for python 3.5 and I think that is because this packet [python-all-dev](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python-all-dev) is just for python 2.7 and I need a similar packet but for python 3.5 ... Can somebody point me one out ? Thank you

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/sid/python3-all-dev?

Comment: I've updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36762382/5997596), can we close this question?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov sure !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyaudio could not import \_portaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681836/pyaudio-could-not-import-portaudio)