# Error importing pyaudio on M1 mac: Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'

Tags: python, installation, pip, pypi, pyaudio

I am able to successfully install portaudio and pyaudio but when I do the following I get an error:
`import pyaudio`
The error is:

```
>>> import pyaudio
Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/S2T/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    import pyaudio._portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/S2T/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap
  Referenced from: /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/S2T/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/envs/S2T/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

I have an M1 mac(Big Sur). Tried on python 3.6, 3.8 and 3.9 version
I have tried all steps from various stackoverflow thread but still get the same error. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Threads tried:
[pyaudio could not import _portaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681836/pyaudio-could-not-import-portaudio)
[Unable to install PyAudio on M1 Mac [PortAudio already installed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251169/unable-to-install-pyaudio-on-m1-mac-portaudio-already-installed)